# Changes to Django Context not showing in template

Tags: python, django, templates, caching, mod-wsgi

I have a template that has variables printing from a Context that I created in a view. It has been working perfectly for a couple of months.

I have added some new variables to the context, but they won't show up in the template.

When I run the Django project locally, if I remove a comma in between two of the variables in the context, I get an error, as expected. Then if I add the comma back, the new variables will be in the template. But when I push the changes to Openshift, the new variables never show up. In fact, if I remove some of the existing variables, the template still renders as if they were there.

I have cleared the cache in my browser. Didn't fix it. I'm not using caching in Django (a search for 'cache' in settings.py shows no hits).

Clearly, something is caching something somewhere, but I can't figure out where. Since my changes occasionally show up in my browser when running locally, I'm confident that there aren't any syntax errors in the python code. Here is the context listing:

```
        context = {
         'slug': 'Admin Home .'
        , 'players': len(players)
        , 'paid': totalPaid
        , 'unpaid': len(unpaid)
        , 'monday': monday
        , 'tuesday': tuesday
        , 'wednesday': wednesday
        , 'donations': donations
        , 'ssmall': ssmall
        , 'smedium': smedium
        , 'slarge': slarge
        , 'sxl': sxl
        , 'sxxl': sxxl
        , 'page': page
    }
```

Here is an example of one of the variables not showing up in the template:

```
    Large: {{slarge}}
```

And the slarge variable has a value. I checked it by running some of the code in the shell, and like I said above, occasionally it shows up on the rendered page.

I also changed the page title in the head section, and those changes only show up occasionally as well, whenever the variable populates correctly on the page.

From what I've read, it sounds like the Apache and/or mod_wsgi that Openshift uses is caching something(s), but I don't know how to fix it. I have restarted the application within Openshift, but that hasn't fixed it.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: In a standard server you would have to restart Apache, since you are using OpenShift you probably need to issue a `rhc app-restart` command, see https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/common-rhc-commands.html

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the HTML is not cached when doing an HTTP request. What your navigator will cache is the CSS, javascript, images, etc. When requesting a webpage, the navigator always render the HTML that it received.

I run a website with nginx and django, and by experience I can tell you that most of times when making changes in to the applications (Python files), it is necessary to **restart django**. (This may be a setting in django)

Unless you setup ca cache in your templates (which require many settings), any modification of a template will always be automatically rendered in your website. By default django does not cache the templates, and it process them every time that they are requested.

Django is your framework, and apache is your server. To make your website work, there must be two daemons, one for apache, and one for django.

Restarting apache will not restart the code of your django apps. What you need to do, is to restart the daemon that runs your django framework.

Your code works as expected when you run it locally, because you are reloading your django framework each time that you use the command `python manage.py runserver..`

Comment: Your description of Django loading changes immediately has always been my experience . . . up until now. When I run it locally, it _doesn't_ show the changes unless I intentionally make a coding error in the view. Then, after fixing the error, the change will show in one browser, but not a different one. I'll see if I can find a way to restart the django daemon, but Openshift doesn't give a lot of control over that kind of thing. I have restarted the web app from within the Openshift console, and that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I should have mentioned, this is my first Django project.

I was making all of these changes in the get section of a class rather than the post section, and it should have been in the post section.